EasyPHP-Devserver-17 dashboard page doesn' launch
After installing EasyPHP-Devserver-17 I try to launch the dashboard page to add a workdirectory, the dashboard doesn't launch, do you know why please ?
I don't know what I can try. It seems like the path to the dashboard is not correct: http://127.0.0.1:1111/ doesn't work.

What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you facing any specific error message?

Hello thx for your answer, yes I have an error message "Connection failed
Firefox cannot establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:1111."

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is there any process running on the given port?
